# Instrucción return vacía en función no-void ¿comportamiento indefinido?

Tags: c, estándares

Investigando sobre las consecuencias de utilizar mal la instrucción `return` en funciones `void` y no-`void` en el [estándar de C](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf) me di cuenta que no especifica<sup>1</sup> qué sucede cuando una función no-`void` usa una instrucción `return` vacía o una función `void` usa una instrucción `return` no vacía:

```
int devolver_entero() { return; }  // no-void usa una return vacio
```

Lo que he podido encontrar en el estándar es lo siguiente (las traducciones son mías):

> ### 6.8.6.4 La instrucción return
>
> #### Restricciones
>
> 1. Una instrucción `return` con una expresión no debe aparecer en una función cuyo tipo de retorno sea `void`. Una instrucción `return` sin una expresión debe aparecer sólo en funciones cuyo tipo de retorno sea `void`.

La cita del estándar anterior establece lo que **debe** hacerse con las instrucciones `return` para funciones que devuelvan o no devuelvan valor, pero en otra parte del estándar establece lo que sucede cuando no se siguen las restricciones:

> ### 6.9.1 Definiciones de funciones
>
> 12. Si se alcanza el `}` que termina la función y el valor de la llamada a la función es usado por el llamante, el comportamiento es indefinido.

La anterior cita del estándar indica que se incurre en comportamiento indefinido si se usa el valor devuelto por una función que ha llegado a la llave de cierre `}`, así que el siguiente ejemplo tenemos comportamiento indefinido:

```
int comportamiento_indefinido(int x) { if (x) return x; }

printf("%d", comportamiento_indefinido(1)); // Correcto
printf("%d", comportamiento_indefinido(0)); // Comportamiento indefinido
```

En la llamada `comportamiento_indefinido(1)` la función devuelve `1` a través de la instrucción `return` bajo el condicional `if (x)`; en la llamada `comportamiento_indefinido(0)` la condición `if (x)` no se cumple y finaliza la función al alcanzar la llave de cierre `}`, usando el retorno de la llamada `comportamiento_indefinido(0)` es comportamiento indefinido (mas no lo es usar el retorno de `comportamiento_indefinido(1)`). Pero ¿qué pasa en este caso?

```
int comportamiento_indefinido(int x) { if (x) return; } // return vacio

printf("%d", comportamiento_indefinido(1)); // Comportamiento indefinido?
printf("%d", comportamiento_indefinido(0)); // Comportamiento indefinido
```

En el ejemplo anterior la llamada `comportamiento_indefinido(1)` no cumple con lo indicado en `§6.9.1/12` para alcanzar comportamiento indefinido, ya que la función finaliza sin alcanzar la llave de cierre `}` y tampoco devuelve valor alguno.

¿Qué parte del estándar de C tiene en cuenta esto?

---

<sup>1</sup>O al menos no lo supe encontrar.

Comment: Independientemente de que el estándar contemple o no contemple estas situaciones lo cierto es que un algoritmo así jamás debería llegar a producción. Cualquiera de estas situaciones genera un warning (este aspecto me sigue pareciendo bastante serio ya que deberían ser errores) que debería ser correctamente atendido. Yo además soy partidario de tratar los warning como errores, por lo que el programa directamente no compilaría.

Comment: @eferion si, también soy amigo de `-werror`, pero el tratamiento que le demos a las alarmas no es el tema de la pregunta. Me gustaría saber qué debo interpretar, estándar en mano, en esa situación.

Comment: Hace no muchó leí en un blog que estadísticamente la gente nueva cometía menos errores a la hora de resolver códigos (en competición) y el motivo principal es la tendencia a regirnos por reglas más estrictas cuando tenemos una base de conocimiento suficiente. No hace falta revisar ningún estándar para saber que eso no se ha de hacer. Una función SIEMPRE ha de devolver algo porque es lo que aquel que la consuma va a esperar y un método NUNCA ha de devolver nada porque nadie va a hacerle caso.

Comment: @eferion es un debate interesante, tal vez da para chat, pero sigue sin ser respuesta a lo que ha motivado mi pregunta. Si bien es cierto que esto *no debería suceder* quiero saber lo que el estándar define que *puede pasar* en caso de que suceda (que si puede suceder: sucederá).

Comment: Además C tiene el añadido de que es un lenguaje que casi roza el ensamblador y con muchos años a sus espaldas que es utilizado en infinidad de sistemas. Esto hace que corregir defectos del lenguaje sea complicado porque es complejo evaluar todas las posibilidades. Lo mejor es evitar las malas prácticas ya que raramente son necesarias. Y en serio entiendo que quieras conocer cual es el comportamiento que dicta el estándar... pero creo que es una de esas situaciones en las que no es necesario ser tan estricto y simplemente basta con saber que ese código no es correcto.

Comment: @eferion mira este ejemplo, conceptualmente es válido ¿qué debo esperar de ello? `double my_sqrt(double d) { if (d<.0) return; /*salimos si d es inoperable*/ return sqrt(d); }` es evidente que no es la manera de solucionar el problema de raíz cuadrada pero **conceptualmente** es algo válido y es código que he visto aceptado en producción.

Comment: Si compila, que siendo C compilará, yo ni me molestaría en mirar el estándar porque lo primero que me queda claro es que ese código es incorrecto. C deja hacer muchas cosas y no por ello han de ser válidas (como castear un puntero a un char, por ejemplo). Yo he visto código similar y sí, vale, compila y aparentemente funciona... pero luego he visto dolores de cabeza porque al cambiar de compilador el programa ni tan siquiera arrancaba.

Comment: @eferion *luego he visto dolores de cabeza porque al cambiar de compilador el programa ni tan siquiera arrancaba* y ahí la importancia de saber qué comportamiento define el estándar en ciertas situaciones. Si el compilador no sigue el estándar entonces el problema es otro :)

Comment: Viendo la gente que habitualmente responde a problemas de C yo te diría que la mejor opción es plantearlo en la versión inglesa. La cantidad de gente que te puede responder es sustancialmente mayor y ahí hay gente cuyo corazón late gracias a un bucle hecho en C.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46457/discussion-between-paperbirdmaster-and-eferion).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La pregunta me parece muy interesante y relevante. Por ejemplo, uno no siempre tiene acceso para corregir un código, pero sería interesante entender qué hace. Por ejemplo saber si es un fallo de seguridad.

Me parece que puede entenderse que ambos casos son equivalentes. En realidad, al ser **un "`no debe`" no tiene que complilar** si está estrictamente en C99, ¿no? Porque de lo contrario debería decir "`no debería`". Ya que [el estándar original (en inglés)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf) dice:

> ### 6.8.6.4 The `return` statement
>
> #### Constraints
>
> A `return` statement with an expression shall not appear in a function whose return type is `void`. A `return` statement without an expression shall only appear in a function whose return type is `void`.

Y el mismo estándar dice (negritas mías):

> ### 4. Conformance
>
> In this International Standard, ‘‘shall’’ is to be interpreted **as a requirement** on an implementation or on a program; conversely, ‘‘shall not’’ is to be interpreted **as a prohibition**.
>   2 If a ‘‘shall’’ or ‘‘shall not’’ requirement that appears outside of a constraint is violated, **the behavior is undefined**. **Undefined behavior is otherwise indicated** in this International Standard by the words ‘‘undefined behavior’’ or **by the omission of any explicit definition of behavior. There is no difference** in emphasis among these three; they all describe ‘‘behavior that is undefined’’.

Es decir, **si no dice nada** sobre el comportamiento, **entonces es indefinido**.

¿Qué sucederá la mayoría de las veces? Imagino que para el compilador es equivalente, porque un `return` sin expresión se compila como `ret` (o equivalente) en la mayoría de las plataformas, al igual que no poner ninguno. Mientras que con argumento, se convierte en mover a un registro o empujar en la pila el resultado de la expresión, y luego volver. Por ejemplo, un `return 8;` puede ser un `mov ax,8` o un `push 8` antes del `ret`. Si no se indica ningún `return` en C, igual el compilador debe incluir un `ret` en ensamblador, tenga o no tenga tipo la función, como si se hubiese hecho `return;`. ¿Se entiende lo que digo?

**EDITADO**: Remuevo referencia a otro RFC y consdieraciones sobre estándares de facto, al encontrar que el mismo estándar lo define.

Comment: No estoy familiarizado con el documento `RFC 2119` ¿qué es?

Comment: El `RFC 2119` aclara el significado de distintos términos. SHALL es una obligación. Mientras que SHOULD es una recomendación. @PaperBirdMaster

Comment: La aclaración la entendí; lo que no entiendo es la relevancia, origen, contexto y relación con el estándar de C del documento `RFC 2119`.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster `shall`, `shold`, etc suelen ser términos confusos. Evidentemente, los `RFC` son documentos del modelo TCP/IP, no tienen nada que ver con los estándares de C y C++. En TCP/IP se definen en dicho RFC para no tener que definirlos en cada RFC del modelo. C define, en su propio estándar, definido *shall* y *shall not*, mientras que el estándar de C++ no, supongo que porque los hereda del estándar de C, que es normativo en C++ si no me equivoco.

Comment: @Peregring-lk insisto: no tengo problemas con el `shall` y el `should`, entiendo la diferencia y entiendo las aclaraciones realizadas en este hilo. La duda que me ha surgido a raíz de las aclaraciones es ¿por qué `RFC 2119` debe considerarse relevante en el contexto de la pregunta? Por otro lado esta pregunta es **sólo C** el estándar C++ define este comportamiento de manera diferente.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Y yo he dicho: "los RFC son documentos del modelo TCP/IP, no tienen nada que ver con los estándares de C y C++". Es decir, te estoy dando la razón, no tiene nada que ver, solo he aclarado adicionalmente que C define *shall* y *shall not* (pero no *should*) de manera independiente en su documento, y C++ supongo que lo hará a través de las definiciones dadas en el estándar de C.

Comment: @Peregring-lk ya me di cuenta antes de que *me estabas dando la razón* respecto al `rfc 2119` ;) pero C++ sigue sin ser relevante en esta pregunta, los diferentes tratamientos de ambos estándares y la influencia del estándar de C en el de C++ da para un largo e interesante debate que por desgracia no debemos tener aquí.

Comment: El RFC 2119 era como ejemplo (lo que digo arriba de estándar de facto). Sin embargo, después encontré que el estándar mismo lo define.

Comment: @ESL muy interesante análisis; con esto podemos pensar que esto está a la vez prohibido y no definido (lo cuál es raro). Sin embargo podemos ver que en realidad no está prohibido ya que los códigos puestos como ejemplo compilan ergo ¿sólo nos queda que es indefinido?

Answer (score 4):

> ## 4. Conformance
>
> 2. If a ‘‘shall’’ or ‘‘shall not’’ requirement that appears outside of a constraint is violated, the
>      behavior is undefined. [...].

(En Español) Es decir, que si una restricción del estándar, de las que vienen indicadas por *shall* (= debe) o *shall not* (= no debe) no es cumplida por un programa, dicho programa contiene comportamiento indefinido.

Y como cita @ESL:

> ### 6.8.6.4 The `return` statement
>
> #### Constraints
>
> A `return` statement with an expression shall not appear in a function whose return type is `void`. A `return` statement without an expression shall only appear in a function whose return type is `void`.

(En Español) Es decir, que si una función `void` intenta devolver algo (`return expr;`), o si una función con un tipo diferente a `void` intenta no devolver nada (`return;`), el comportamiento es indefinido (*undefined behaviour*).

En tu caso, dado que tu sentencia `return` aparece sin valor en una función que requiere un valor de retorno, es comportamiento indefinido de acuerdo al punto *4.2*.

Inversamente, ésto también sería comportamiento indefinido:

```
void f() { return 4; }
```

Estas definiciones están sacadas de:

- Committee Draft [n1570.pdf](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) - April 12, 2011 ISO/IEC 9899:201x

Comment: ¿Esta cita de **Conformance** forma parte del estándar C o sale de otro documento? Si sale del estándar C ¿puedes señalar la versión del estándar que has consultado y la sección a la que pertenece?

Comment: Del estándar de C. He añadido más aclaraciones y el documento de donde saco mis definiciones.

Comment: *Estas definiciones están sacadas de: C-WD-n1570.pdf*. El enlace al documento ayudaría más ;) De todas maneras Abril de 2012 es más moderno que los estándares que estaba consultando yo: [May'05](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf) y [Sep'07](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf). Por otro lado **creo que** comportamiento indefinido es cuando está expresado como tal en el estándar, si el estándar no dice nada ¿no sería comportamiento no especificado?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster También tengo el de Mayo de 2005 y dicen exáctamente lo mismo.

Comment: Si, ciertamente la sección de "Conformance" no parece haber cambiado en años :)

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Añadido enlace as well.

Comment: Además, @PaperBirdMaster, el mismo estándar dice que cuando algo no se indica, es indefinido: "***Undefined behavior is otherwise indicated in this International Standard** by the words ‘‘undefined behavior’’ or **by the omission of any explicit definition of behavior***"