# warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]

Tags: c

en esta función me esta dando un warning al compilar, a que se debe ? leí que es cuando uno declara una función int y esta no retorna ningún valor, pero en este caso mi función es void, entonces no entiendo el error.

```
void *ATERRIZAR(void *datos_avion)
    {
        int i;
        AVION *ptr_datos = (AVION*)datos_avion;
        printf("\nCASA");
        sem_wait(&pistas_aviones);
        i = 0;
        while(pistas[i].num_llegada != 0)
        {
            i = (i+1)%num_pistas;
        }
        pistas[i].num_llegada = ptr_datos->num_llegada;
        pistas[i].num_pasajeros = ptr_datos->num_pasajeros;
        pistas[i].prioridad = ptr_datos->prioridad;
        sleep(1);
        printf("AVION %d ATERRIZA EN PISTA %d\n",ptr_datos->num_llegada , i);
        sleep(1);
        DESOCUPAR_PISTA(i);
        sem_post(&pistas_aviones);
    }
```

Comment: Lo dice bien claro: La función no devuelve `void` y se acaba sin devolver nada.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El mensaje de error es de lo más esclarecedor y auto-explicativo, permíteme traducirlo:

> ```
> warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
> ```

> ```
> alarma: el control alcanza el final de una función no-void [-Wreturn-type]
> ```

En otras palabras, la función no devuelve `void` y se acaba sin devolver nada. Si te fijas la función devuelve un **puntero a `void`**:

```
  void *ATERRIZAR(void *datos_avion)
//^^^^^^ <----------- puntero a void
```

Pero no hay ni una sola instrucción `return` en `ATERRIZAR`.

Te lo marca como alarma en lugar de error porque que la función no devuelva nada a pesar de haber dicho en su declaración que sí lo devuelve es **potencialmente** peligroso. Potencialmente en cuanto a que no va a pasar nada a no ser que uses el valor retornado por la función `ATERRIZAR`, que al no haber sido asignado dentro de la función provocará un comportamiento indefinido. Puedes ver más detalles sobre eso [en esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/26479/instrucci%c3%b3n-return-vac%c3%ada-en-funci%c3%b3n-no-void-comportamiento-indefinido).

En mi opinión esto debería ser un error pero lo marca como alarma, si activas la opción del compilador indicada en la propia alarma (`-Wreturn-type`) pasará a ser considerado error en lugar de alarma.

Comment: Gracias master me quedo clarisimo.

Comment: Si esta respuesta responde correctamente a la pregunta, deberías marcarla como aceptada para a) que otros usuarios tengan claro que es la solución correcta cuando tengan tu mismo problema y b) darle a PaperBirdMaster los puntos correspondientes.